# Casting to generic parameter in java

Tags: java, generics, casting, enums

I have a class `EnumSet<E extends Enum<E>>` that has a method `public void include(E e)` that takes a enum constant and puts it into a list, representing a set of that given enum.

Now I want to load EnumSets from a xml file via reflection, so that I can iterate ove rall enum constants and include them in the loaded set.

```
Object[] enum_const = Class.forName(cur.getAttributeValue("type")).getEnumConstants();
field.set(obj, Class.forName(cur.getAttributeValue("type")).newInstance());
for (Object o : enum_const) {
    if (o.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(cur.getText())) {
        ((EnumSet<?>) field.get(obj)).include((E) o);
        // Include each matching EnumConstant..
    }
}
```

The last cast is not possible, because E is not accessible in that context. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Simply remove cast. Template parameters are replaced with Object in raw types.

Comment: Have you tried [EnumSet.allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf%28java.lang.Class%29)?

Comment: Maybe you can access them using [typetools](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.jodah%7Ctypetools%7C0.3.1%7Cjar) library.

Comment: thanks for the quick answers :) but removing the cast is not possible, because the method expects a E parameter and not an object. and if i include all enum constants, i have to exclude specific ones later, so that wont work too :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic helper method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <E extends Enum<E>> void uncheckedInclude(EnumSet<?> enumSet, Object element) {
    EnumSet<E> enumSetWithNarrowedType = (EnumSet<E>) enumSet;
    E elementWithNarrowedType = (E) element;
    enumSetWithNarrowedType.include(elementWithNarrowedType);
}

...

if (o.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(cur.getText())) {
    uncheckedInclude((EnumSet<?>) field.get(obj), o);
}
```

Note that there are two unchecked casts being made here, one for the set and one for the element. The cast from `EnumSet<?>` to `EnumSet<E>` is necessary because generic wildcards can't express the recursive `E extends EnumSet<E>` bound.

Obviously the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is promising that the types will be correct, since even the JVM can't fail fast for a wrong unchecked cast - make sure to document well and ensure the helper method isn't abused.